# Recreating the existing AWS Lambda function in the same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to recreate the existing lambda function in AWS which is in same account without manually redoing the same from scratch? I have an use-case where there is a function which have a lot of dependencies. I need to recreate the same with small modifications without affecting the existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this.

The 'official' answer is to create resources via CloudFormation. You can then deploy the resources again by deploying a new stack from the same template.

You will either need to manually re-create the resources, or create a CloudFormation template to deploy it.

Comment: Sure, thanks for quick response. I will recreate it.

Comment: You can use `parameters` in a CloudFormation template. These are like variables that can insert different values in the infrastructure being deployed. For example, there could be a parameter for **SNS Topic** that is then inserted into the template when deploying the Lambda function.